# 'RequestDeviceOptions': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence

Tags: javascript, web-bluetooth

I am using a modified version of the sample code for Bluetooth [device-information](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html) using the Web Bluetooth API.

The Bluetooth device was tested independently using NRF Connect app on my iPhone and everything works as intended. I used the UARTService ID as indicated on the NRF Connect app and used it to set `OptionalServices`. See the following code snippet.

```
let UARTService = "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"
    let UARTCharRX = "6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"
    let UARTCharTX = "6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"
    let options = {};
    
    //options.services = UARTService;
    
    if (document.querySelector('#allDevices').checked) {
        options.acceptAllDevices = true;
        options.optionalServices = UARTService;
    } else {
        options.filters = filters;
    }

    console.log('Requesting Bluetooth Device.........');
    console.log('with ' + JSON.stringify(options));
    navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options)
        .then(device => {
            console.log('> Name:             ' + device.name);
            console.log('> Id:               ' + device.id);
            console.log('> Connected:        ' + device.gatt.connected);
            return device;
        
        }).then(device => {
            return device.gatt.connect();
        
        }).then(function (server) {
            console.log("Connected ?  " + server.connected);
            return server.getPrimaryService(UARTService);
        
        }).then(function (result) {
            console.log("DEvice information ", result);
        
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('Argh! ' + error);
        });
```

I get the following error:

```
Browser is WebBluetoothEnabled
device-info.js:37 Requesting Bluetooth Device.........
device-info.js:38 with {"acceptAllDevices":true,"optionalServices":"6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"}
device-info.js:57 Argh! TypeError: Failed to execute 'requestDevice' on 'Bluetooth': Failed to read the 'optionalServices' property from 'RequestDeviceOptions': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.
```

Searching for `'RequestDeviceOptions': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.` on stackoverflow and github issues was without answers.

I suspected a wrong Service UUID but on checking twice revealed it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

`optionalServices` needs to be a list:

```
options.optionalServices = [ UARTService ];
```

Comment: Thank you @reilly-grant that worked. feel silly that I overlooked this.